# Can I specify different page sizes for each page when printing programatically?

Tags: c++, winapi, printing

I'm printing multiple pages to a virtual PDF Printer. Not all the pages have the same paper size. Here's the outline of my code:

```
DEVMODE DevMode;
InitDevMode(&DevMode);
SetThePageSize(&DevMode);

HDC hPrinterDC = CreateDC("WINSPOOL", "MyPrinter", NULL, &DevMode);

DOCINFO DocInfo;
memset( &DocInfo, 0, sizeof(DocInfo) );
DocInfo.cbSize = sizeof(DocInfo);

StartDoc(hPrinterDC, &DocInfo);

for (int i = 0; i < nPagesCount; i++)
{
    StartPage(hPrinterDC);

    DoTheDrawing();

    EndPage(hPrinterDC);
}

EndDoc(hPrinterDC);
```

This allows me to select the page size only once. In order to have a different page size for each page I need to somehow update the printing device context with a new DEVMODE before each new StartPage. Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, alter your DevMode with the desired pagesize and call ResetDC(hPrinterDC, DevMode);

EDIT: Oh, and do this after EndPage, but before StartPage.